# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' (10060)

Tags: mysql, centos, digitalocean

Tengo un servidor en DigitalOcean y uso CentOS 8, instale MySQL 8.0.26 y quiero conectarme desde mi pc a MySQL alojado en mi servidor por SSL.

Ya habilite la conexión SSL, después de esto habilite la conexión remota en MySQL editando el archivo mysql-serve.cnf:

```
etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql-serve.cnf
```

añadi estas lineas:

```
[mysqld]
require_secure_transport = ON
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

guarde y reinicie el servicio de mysql, después cree un usuario y una bd para los clientes remotos

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> CREATE DATABASE remotedb;
mysql> CREATE USER 'remoteuser'@'mysql-client-ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' REQUIRE SSL;
```

En 'mysql-client-ip' coloque '%' para que cualquier cliente con su ip pudiese conectarse.

Estando en el servidor puedo conectarme con mi nuevo usuario y si entro, esto aparece si ejecuto el comando status;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya solo queda conectarme desde mi computador a MySQL, lo hago haciendo esto:

```
mysql -h 0.0.0.0 -u remoteuser -p
```

y aquí es donde me resulta el error que es el siguiente:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' (10060)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás confundido con el significado de

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Con esa línea lo único que estás haciendo es decirle a tu servidor MySQL que acepte conexiones desde cualquier IP. En realidad la dirección IP `0.0.0.0` no es una dirección real válida.

Por tanto, para conectar a tu servidor, tendrás que usar la dirección *real* que tenga asignada esa máquina. Por suerte ya la conoces, es la misma que usas para conectarte a la terminal (no tiene por qué ser una IP, puede ser una URL).